# Kann die "als ob"-Struktur die Gegenwart nehmen?

Tags: grammar, conjunction

> Es sieht aus, als ob er ohne seine Freundin ins Kino geht.

Ich bin mir unsicher, ob diese Satzbildung richtig ist. Was ich schon weiß, ist, dass die "als ob"-Struktur bloß im Konjunktiv geht.

Comment: It can take any time in any mode

Comment: [Belles Lettres about this (and other things)](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/konjunktiv.php).

Comment: Die Gegenwart nehmen? Just take the present time! The whole? Well, 40 ounzes, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Konjunktiv-Form of the verb and depending on the context (whether possible or not possible) you use either Konjunktiv I or Konjunktiv II (possibly with *würde*).

In your example above, the sentence structure sounds off. The Objekt should be in front of the place in your example.

> Es sieht aus, als ob er ohne seine Freundin ins Kino gehe.

Comment: Einige meiner Freunde lassen das ob aus.

Comment: If you omit the *ob*, you will need to change the sentence structure again and have the verb follow the *als* directly. --> Es sieht aus, als ginge er ohne Freundin ins Kino.

Comment: Aber das Tätigkeitswort bleibt im Konjunktiv. :)

Comment: I disagree "Du siehst aus, als ob du müde wärst/seist." "Sieht aus, als ob wir warten müssten"...sorry, but no way! Indicative present is the way t go unless you want to contrive a really really theoretical context. I think there is no defined need for anything. In German, it depends on the message, not on the conjunction.

Comment: Just to confirm: You want to say that the examples you just gave are incorrect and you would instead use the Indikativ-form of the verbs, *bist* and *müssen*?

Comment: @Emanuel, can you give an example of *als ob* + indicative in written German?

Comment: @SentryRaven... yes. In the müssen-example, both versions work and have a different meaning... indicative "Looks like we will have to walk", condi: "Looks like we would have to work, if..."

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... http://books.google.de/books?id=H80BJW0N-jYC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22er+sieht+aus,+als+ob+er%22&source=bl&ots=AyOHaRJSOz&sig=rp2n5yQfzpigAzMc8RuDVgHPUyo&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rnbdUt6WO8zNswbLi4DYAw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22er%20sieht%20aus%2C%20als%20ob%20er%22&f=false   it is dialog but using conditional here would sound wrong and there is no mention in the answer about written or spoken German.

Comment: @Emanuel, I agree that one would often use the indicative mode instead of a conditional mode in colloquial speech. Your claim seemed to be stronger, though. And even if one can find examples which are neither dialogue nor children's books, you will have noticed that conditional is used more frequently.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... why say colloquial speech. Let's just say speech. I don't think there is anything colloquial about it. If you were to use conditional too much you would stand out because it doesn't sound like it normally would. That is not colloquial in my opinion. I agree though that in writing condi is prevalent

Comment: @Emanuel, I speak differently in a pub with friends than (not in a pub) in a group of more senior colleagues. But we seem to agree in principle, so it is good that this has been clarified.